# Why can't PHPUnit in Laravel access a route that exists?

Tags: laravel, xampp, phpunit

I'm having a problem when I run a PHPUnit test but not when I try to test the application manually.

My unit test contains

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class UserAdminPanelTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /**
     * Tests that the user/company admin panel is showing data and able to save changes.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testUserAdminPanel()
    {
        $user = factory(App\User::class)->create();

        $this->actingAs($user)
             ->withSession(['foo' => 'bar'])
             ->visit('/')
             ->click('User')
             ->seePageIs('/user/3')
             ->see('Edit')
             ->click('Edit');   // There's more after this but this is where I get the error
    }
}
```

and my routes are

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/', function () {   
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::resource('user', 'UserController',
            ['except' => ['create', 'store', 'destroy']]);

    });

});
```

and the error I get when I try to run my test is

```
There was 1 failure:

1) UserAdminPanelTest::testUserAdminPanel
A request to [http://localhost/usbsinc/public/user/3/edit] failed. Received status code [404].

C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:178
C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:72
C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:53
C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:706
C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\tests\UserAdminPanelTest.php:27
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129

Caused by
exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:161
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(823): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(691): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(675): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(246): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(124): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(103): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(99): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests.php(480): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php(70): Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->call('GET', 'http://localhos...', Array, Array, Array)
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->makeRequest('GET', 'http://localhos...')
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php(706): Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->visit('http://localhos...')
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\tests\UserAdminPanelTest.php(27): Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase->click('Edit')
#20 [internal function]: UserAdminPanelTest->testUserAdminPanel()
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php(909): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(UserAdminPanelTest), Array)
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php(768): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest()
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestResult.php(612): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php(724): PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(Object(UserAdminPanelTest))
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php(747): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestSuite.php(747): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\usbsinc\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php(440): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#28 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#29 C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#30 C:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#31 {main}
```

I've dug and dug but I can't figure out what's happening or even *how* something like this could happen. Any hints on some debug code or what might be going on?

Comment: The server logs (XAMPP) don't show any errors or even access by PHPUnit (which it would if it was logging anything from PHPUnit because there are other successful tests that are accessing pages).

Comment: Hey P.H.P ;) Did you get a solution to this issue. It's come up for me too

Comment: I just added the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I was using the method `Click`, which will click an anchor tag but my view had an HTML5 `button` element called "Edit" instead. I switched the method to `Press` and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and fixed it this way:

Goto
line 140 of /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php

Dump and die the $request inside of function match(Request $request) by adding this code and running phpunit from the command line.

```
dd($request);
```

Now, check out the "REQUEST_URI" of the dumped array.

I found this was incorrect for me, my app_path appeared to be duplicated and this lead me back to the source of my problem which was in a modification I made to the tests/TestCase.php class.

Make sure $baseUrl is correctly set:

```
protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';
```

I'd updated this in trying to fix an issue with my .env file and forgot to change it back. Let me know if this fixes your issue!

Comment: That could have been the issue, @Mike, but that wasn't the problem in my case. Thanks for your thoughtful input. I'm sure it'll be helpful to others having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, `APP_URL` value in .env file should start with `http://` otherwise `RouteCollection` fails to match the request created by `MakesHttpRequest`

`APP_URL=http://myproject.test` => Works

`APP_URL=myproject.test` => Doesn't Work